# HP UFT/QTP: change code and backtrack while debugging

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

When running scripts or lines of code, is there way during debug when the code is paused, to change a few lines of code (currently locked and cannot drag the yellow arrow either to backtrack) and then continue instead of having to stop the code, change and then start all over again?

This application is a pain to use.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in UFT nor in any other test automation tool (possibly).
while debugging if you want to see how a line of code may run without actually running it through execution, you may use the console.

for example if you written a code to verify a text but you forgot to click on an object that would make the text visible, then while debugging before you execute the code that verifies the text, you can execute the code to click on object in the console

```
Object.Click 'press enter'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change your code during code execution.In Visula studio you can execute some code during debaging.
On the other handin QTP you can change the values ​​of your variables during the debug mode, but forgot about code change during debug.